# Why page is blank when I include mootools in ASP.NET MVC 2 Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, mootools

I included mootools le this

```
<script language="javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/mootools-core-1.3.1-full-compat.js")%>' type="text/javascript"/>
```

It compiles but when running it's blank page. If I remove page shows up again. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double `type` and also your script tags aren't properly closed, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/mootools-core-1.3.1-full-compat.js")%>'></script>
```